# iAds "Invalid content size 'ADBannerContentSizePortrait' passed to ADAdSizeForBannerContentSize" in iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder, iad, ios-4.2

**Update 12/16/2010:** It looks like there is a similar issue when targeting 4.0 devices with the 4.2 SDK... your app will crash immediately if you used Interface Builder to create your ad banner view. Weak-linking the iAd framework and Re-creating the ad banner implementation on the code side of things was the fix. Thanks to this thread by Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

**---**

Hi, I just tried to run my app using iOS 4.2 SDK (final) and targeting iOS 4.0 devices, and even though my app compiles fine, I get this error immediately upon running...

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'Invalid content size 'ADBannerContentSizePortrait' passed to
 ADAdSizeForBannerContentSize'
...
```

I tried...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
}
```

... but no luck, still getting the same crash error. In IB it looks like the only options for "Sizes" are "Portrait, Landscape, or Both" which I guess iOS 4.0 is not a fan of.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
}`

to 
`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait //or landscape
}`

what you had was deprecated meaning its no longer supported as of iOS 4.2

Comment: thanks - i was originally setting the banner size in IB, which seems to also be fixed by removing & re-adding the iAd framework to the project.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. It seems that the os versions below 4.2 still want the deprecated content size identifiers, at least when the ADBannerView is created in Interface Builder. I also have the iAd framework weak-linked as a precaution. I hope this is helpful to someone, and thanks so much to the great community on this site for all the wonderful information and insight!

```
// if the current version of the os is less than 4.2, use the old way of defining the banner size
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"4.2" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    adBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];

    adBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;

    NSLog(@"below 4.2");

} else {

    adBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];

    adBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

    NSLog(@"4.2 or above");

}
```

Comment: Works great. I use float comparison with 'systemVersion' instead: ``if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 4.2)``

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you remove the iAd framework and re-add it using "Add existing framework..." this fixes the issue... weird. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The only issue now is, I haven't been able to successfully load an ad in the simulator (4.0 and 4.2)... getting this error in bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: 'Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"'

Comment: Another note - this does actually work on the device... just not in the simulator. I think it may be a router or little snitch related issue. All set now!

Answer (score 0):

The answer that is found in the "update" of the question is correct. Note that at this time of this writing, the [thread by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app) needs updating because it uses deprecated iAd constants. Otherwise it is a very good resource for solving this problem.